# Particle system - not all particles have a texture sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a particle system, set duration to 1 second and particle count to 15. I also created a material, added a sprite to it and then set that material in particle system Renderer options. However, when running the particle system in scene editor, 15 particles are emitted but only 5 or 6 have the sprite material shown, the other particles are just empty, without any material. Sometimes 10 out of 15 particles have a visible sprite material, sometimes even less and it always varies.

Could the problem be in some rendering option or with particle lifetime?

What could be wrong? I don't do anything in code other than calling .Play()

```
psEffect.Play();
```

This is what the problem looks like:

[image]

You can see that lots of emitted particles dont have the star sprite.

Settings:

Duration: 1.00
Start Delay: 0
Start lifetime: 1
Start speed: 10
Start size: constant between 1 and 3
Start rotation: constant between 0 and 270

Emission
Rate over time: 25

Shape
Shape: Sphere
Radius: 1, thickness: 1
Arc: 1
Texture: 2D sprite that you can see on image above
Scale: X 7, Y 1, Z 1

Renderer:
Render mode: billboard
Material: I created a new material
Min particle size: 0
Max particle size: 0.5
Order in layer: 10

Comment: To reproduce the problem, settings of the particle system are required (and probably your Unity version).

Comment: @trollingchar Updated OP with much more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It's caused by the Texture field in the Shape section.

It's in that section for some reason. Actually, it controls *the shape of the particle cloud* by altering particles' colors including alpha, not the individual particle's texture.

Particle system without that setting:

[image]

...and with:

[image]

The texture used:

[image]

It's unclear for me how their colors are determined when **Shape** is **Sphere** but if we look at this angle (system is not rotated, and red arrow points away from us), we can see a coincidence:

[image]

The same if **Shape** is a flat **Circle**:

[image]

You stated that you have already created a material for particles' rendering, and I see that it works properly. I have done that too:

[image]

The result (of course with shape texture disabled):

[image]

No invisible particles.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem was that I had a sprite set as texture in Shape settings for the particle system. I removed the sprite from Texture in Shape settings and it works correctly now!